# Ag-grid getRowStyle doesn't work properly

Tags: ag-grid, clojurescript, ag-grid-react, reagent

I am trying to implement a row style such that if important columns are missing a value, then it should be red (like an alert). I have the following logic:

```
(defn missing-requirements? [params]
  (not (every? (js->clj (.-data params)) @state/important-tags)))
```

And this is the main function that is being rendered

```
(def ag-adapter (r/adapt-react-class (.-AgGridReact js/agGridReact)))

(defn home-page []
  [:div [:h2 "Ekspono tag-model"]
   [:p "My portfolio / Top Index " [:a {:style {:background-color "#C0C0C0" :float "right" :color "black"}
                                        :href "https://www.google.com" :target "_blank"} "Show problems"]]
   [:div {:className "ag-theme-balham" :style {:height 200 :width 700 :color "purple"}}
    [ag-adapter {:modules "AllCommunityModules"
                 :columnDefs  @state/cols
                 :rowData @state/rows
                 :defaultColDef {:sortable true
                                 :filter "agTextColumnFilter"
                                 :floatingfilter true
                                 :resizable true
                                 :flex 1
                                 :width deafult-col-w}
                 :getRowStyle (fn [params] (if (error/missing-requirements? params) {:background-color "Green"}))
                 :sidebars "filters"
                 :onGridReady (fn [params] 
                                (:gridApi (.-api params))
                                (:gridColumnApi (.-columnApi params)))}]]])
```

Just :rowStyle {:background-color "red"} works fine. Does someone know what could be wrong? I have ag-grid-react version 21.0.1-1 as a dependency.

Comment: There isn't really enough here to test. We don't know what `params` looks like , or the rest of your table code. Ideally you'd boil it down to a small code sample that we can easily run for ourselves. That said it stands out to me here that the example you said works uses `rowStyle` while the one you said doesn't uses `getRowStyle`. If that's not it I'd look at the hiccup (vectors) that's returned and make sure it looks how you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by adding #js as shown below

```
:getRowStyle (fn [params] (if (error/missing-requirements? params) #js {:background-color "Green"}))
```